# Vba comboBoxes how to use the Index to get the value

Tags: excel, vba

I have combo box in a userform and I would like to get the values of a combo box into an array first I need to use the index of the value in a combo box to populate the array but using the .listIndex=number gives me false here is my code any help appreciated

```
Private Sub countItemsOnThecombo()
Dim itemOnCombo As Long
Dim itemd As Integer
Dim Comboarr() As String

itemOnCombo = Me.ComboBox1.ListCount
MsgBox "1The list count" & itemOnCombo
MsgBox "2with the index" & UserForm1.ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
'ReDim Comboarr(itemOnCombo)
'For itemd = 1 To UBound(Comboarr)
'Comboarr(itemd) = Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = itemd
'MsgBox Comboarr(itemd) 'Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex = itemd 'Comboarr(itemd)
'Next itemd


End Sub
```

Comment: Why can't you just use `ComboBox1.List`?

Comment: @SJR    sorry did not get that to work with list. Just to rephrase the question I am interested in getting the list from combo box  **into an array** and if I can use the index to loop through the values

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand what you are doing because that's what the List property does. See eg https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/215899-need-loop-through-all-items-combobox.html

Comment: @SJR thanks  got it now